# How can I use the parameterized method in my code or get the result from the method?

Tags: c#

We need to create a simple calculator using parameterized constructor/methods

```
//I declared some local variables for the parameter
Console.WriteLine("Enter first number: ");
double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter second number: ");
double num2= Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter operator: ");
char operation = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
double result;

//I used switch-case for the method
static void Calcu(char operation, double num1, double num2, double result)
{
    switch (operation)
    {
        case '+':
            result = num1 + num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + result);
            break;

        case '-':
            result = num1 - num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Difference: "+ result);
            break;

        case '*':
            result = num1 * num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Product: "+ result);
            break;

        case '/':
            result = num1 / num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Quotient: "+ result);
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator");
            break;
    }
    
}
```

I am having trouble in getting the result from the method and printing the result outside the method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: You could let your currently unused(?) `Calcu()` method return a `String` (instead of `void`) and add a corresponding `Console.WriteLine(Calcu(operation, num1, num2, result))` line to the main part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that your method returns something, right now it returns nothing `void`.

Changing `void` to `double` signals that this method will return a double.

You are also passing the result into the `Calcu()` method which I doubt you want. You should specify the result as a variable within the method then return that variable.

I'm guessing this is what you mean.

```
static double Calcu(char operation, double num1, double num2)
{
    double result;

    switch (operation)
    {
        case '+':
            result = num1 + num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + result);
            break;

        case '-':
            result = num1 - num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Difference: "+ result);
            break;

        case '*':
            result = num1 * num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Product: "+ result);
            break;

        case '/':
            result = num1 / num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Quotient: "+ result);
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator");
            break;
    }

    return result
}
```

Then take in your variables, and then pass them to the method.

```
//I declared some local variables for the parameter
Console.WriteLine("Enter first number: ");
double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter second number: ");
double num2= Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter operator: ");
char operation = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

Calcu(operation, num1, num2);
```

EDIT: sorry terrible formatting